# date syntax issue in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date, syntax, alter

I keep getting this error message when trying to change the data type of my column:

```
alter table x modify column order_date date NOT NULL;
```

ERROR at line 1

> ORA-00905 missing keyword

I not sure where I am going wrong, as I am aware there are many types of dates in sql?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MODIFY clause does not take COLUMN as a keyword.  This will work:

```
alter table x modify order_date date NOT NULL;
```

The syntax is documented in the Oracle SQL reference.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_3001.htm#i2133121).

We only need to include COLUMN with commands which have several different possibilities.  For instance, with the ALTER TABLE ... DROP command, because we can drop columns, constraints or partitions....

```
alter table x drop column order_date ;
```

---

> "when I tried entering NOT NULL, it said the table needed to be empty"

You should be able to apply a NOT NULL constraint, providing all the rows in the table have a value in the `order_date` column.  The error message you get is quite clear:

```
ORA-01758 table must be empty to add mandatory (NOT NULL) column
```

This means your column has some rows without values.  So, you need to update the table and populate those rows with some value; what you will use as a default depends on your business rules.

Comment: Great answer thanks alot, but when I tried entering NOT NULL, it said the table needed to be empty so specify that NOT NULL parameter, which doesnt make sense as that field shouldnt affect the rest?

Comment: ORA-01758 table must be empty to add mandatory (NOT NULL) column